# the type of map's key

Tags: c++, stl

Just saw a question on STL.  The question is
"<"does not need to be overloaded when  the key of map belongs to certain types.
What are these types?

Don't quite understand this question! Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'd guess primitive types and any other kind of data for which `operator<` is already defined.

Comment: Native types where '<' works naturally anyway?

Comment: @RedX: PODs?  Really?  Do you mean primitive types?

Comment: @Oli I guess calling it primitive types is better. But i think it's clear what i mean :-).

Comment: @RedX: "POD" is something quite different (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).

Comment: @Oli i know that POD is a type of structure. And seeing as you were correct i corrected my comment.

Comment: @trojanfoe: pointers can be used as keys aswell as far as i know, and you cant use `<` on pointers.

Comment: @smerlin: msdn disagrees with you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5wt12d.aspx

Comment: @rubenvb: That MSDN page is talking about what happens in MSVC, it doesn't apply to C++ implementations in general. The reason you can use pointers in a map is that map uses `std::less` by default. `std::less` is required by the standard to work for any pair of pointers of the same type, even if `<` does not work for the same pair of pointers.

Comment: Well, or maybe it could be read to refer to any implementation, but the point is "Comparison of pointers is guaranteed valid only when the pointers refer to objects in the same array", I'm not sure whether that's intended to mean "only this much is guaranteed by the standard, although we do the address comparison above", or if it's intended to mean "notwithstanding the address comparison we described above, if the pointers aren't within the same object forget about it". This caveat is not true of `std::less` - so you can use pointers as keys in a map anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the map is instantiated with the default comparator (i.e. as `map<Key,Value>` with no third argument):

- Built-in numeric types
- Pointers
- Any type for which `std::less<Key>` has been specialised (as long as the specialisation doesn't require `operator<`).
- Pedantically, any type which already has an overload of `operator<`.

For any other key type, the map will try to compare them using an expression like `key1 < key2`, which will only compile if there is an overload of `operator<` for the key type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, primitive types for which `<` is already defined.